# using python read a column 'H' from csv and implement this function SUM(H16:H$280)/H$14*100

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

Using python read a column `'H'` from a dataframe and implement this function:

```py
CDF = {SUM(H1:H$266)/G$14}*100
```

Where:

- `H$266` is the last element of the column, and
- `G$14` is the total sum of the column H.

In sum(), the first variable iterates `(H1, H2, H3 ... H266)` but the last value remains the same `(H$266)`. So the first value of CDF is obviously 100 and then it goes on decreasing downwards.

I want to implement this using dataframe.

Comment: @Quang Hoang can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you could do this:

```py
from pandas import Series

s = Series([1, 2, 3])  # H1:H266 data
sum_of_s = s.sum()  # G14

def calculus(subset, total_sum):
    return subset.sum() / total_sum * 100

result = Series([calculus(s.iloc[i:], sum_of_s) for i in range(len(s))])
print(result)
```

You should adapt it to your dataset, but basically it's the idea. Let me know if it works.